# What is this adventure where the party is stuck in a dungeon with a time machine?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, published-adventures, product-identification

I used to DM for a group in high school and ran a great adventure that involved everyone being stuck in a dungeon with a machine that allowed the party to travel back and forth in time. It was a bit of work keeping track of things changing through the timelines but a great puzzle adventure. I would love to try it again now, but I have had no luck finding it.

**What I remember of the adventure:**

- It was in D&D 3.5e.
- The mechanism for time travel was a bridge in a cube-shaped room. The bridge could move, and you would walk to the other wall (and gravity would change for you and all); each wall was a different time period.
- There was a magic 'elevator' - essentially a hole you jumped down that would loop back up to the top with a portal. If you held the right beads, you would stop at the desired floor.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Take the [tour].  Do you remember whether this adventure was a published module, third party, or something unofficial found elsewhere?

Answer (score 4):

## Hickman's "Anvil of Time" (*Dungeon* #86 13–43)

[*Dungeon* #86](https://paizo.com/products/btpy7tq3?Dungeon-Issue-86) (May/June 2001) includes [Tracy Hickman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy_Hickman)'s **"The Anvil of Time"** (13–43) for *Dungeons & Dragons, Third Edition*. (This adventure dates to well before the [Dragonlance novels series](https://www.amazon.com/gp/bookseries/B00CJBQIHW/ref=dp_st_0786947225) of the same name.)

The adventure is set in [Krynn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragonlance_locations) and involves time travel like the question describes… and to say anything else would kind of ruin the adventure. Suffice it to say, it matches your memory, down to the very specific bead-dependent magic elevator, *plus* it includes a black-and-white line-art illustration of how many beads it takes to reach each floor:

> [image: This illustration is by either Christoper West or Jason Engle. It is unsigned.] <sup>***Tip: Do not attempt without beads!***</sup>

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you so much :D

Comment: @Comradeblade consider accepting this as the "accepted answer".  It'll give both of you rep as well as signify to those reviewing question from the list that you're good.